# How to filter data Paging 3 Android?

Tags: android, rx-android, android-paging-3

I would like to filter data from the current response in Paging 3 using `PagingRx`.
I have tried as mention in [Paging Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-transform#filter-data)

**Used Libraries**

```
def paging_version = "3.0.1"
    //Paging
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$paging_version"
    // alternatively - without Android dependencies for tests
    testImplementation "androidx.paging:paging-common:$paging_version"
    // RxJava3
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-rxjava3:$paging_version"
```

I have tried to filter responses in MyViewModel class as mention in the documentation.

```
// Type is Flowable<PagingData<User>>.
    PagingRx.getFlowable(pager)
      .map(pagingData ->
        pagingData.filter(user -> !user.isHiddenFromUi())
      )
    }
```

Now the problem is I didn't found any `filter` option under `map`. Please have look and let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Facing same problem, Please let me know If you get the solution

Answer (score 2):

The `paging3` documentation is very bad for java. The code samples provided for transforming data using java will never work because the map and filter are placed under a class called `PagingDataTransforms.kt`. I have attached the correct code sample below,

```
PagingRx.getFlowable(pager)
  .map(pagingData -> PagingDataTransforms.filter(pagingData, 
       Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), 
       user -> !user.isHiddenFromUi()));
```